# Optimizing a "coin toss" experiment simulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I would like to optimize the simulation I have written. I'll provide the code I created, and after it I will explain the main idea I would like to achieve:

```
for exp_itrs in range(99999):
    coin_flips = np.zeros((1000,10))
    for toss in range(999):
        toss_10 = np.random.randint(0,2,size = (10))
        coin_flips[toss] = toss_10
```

The general idea of this is to run the following experiment simulation 100,000 times:
tossing 1000 coins, each coin 10 times. Use a numpy matrix of size (1000,10) to record each experiment (the rows represent coins and each column is a single toss).

Right now, it takes about 5 minutes for my PC to run this simple code.

Comment: Why not just do : `coin_flips= np.random.randint(0,2,size = (1000,10))`? Running it once or million times won't change its probability, I would think.

Comment: This is also doing only `99999` simulations and throwing away the results of the first `99998`...

Comment: im fully aware of both your comments. I have posted only a fragment of the full code for simplicity. Divakar's suggestion is great and I'll use it.

Comment: Yes, it's going to take a while: you're doing a billion coin flips.  Doing a billion `pass` iterations takes a bit over a minute on my hardware.

Comment: @Prune ah, the power of numpy: doing a billion random-number generations takes 3 seconds!

Comment: Now that I have tested it, looks like Divakar's suggestion worked like a wonder.

Comment: @מורןרזניק on my machine, I can do all billion random coinflips in under 3 seconds, and use 1gig of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, do something like:

```
import numpy as np
experiment = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100000, 1000, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Note, this only requires 100000*1000*10*1e-9 = 1 gigabytes

In action:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> experiment = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100000, 1000, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> means = experiment.mean(axis=(0,1))
>>> means
array([ 0.50002927,  0.49993242,  0.5000543 ,  0.49999995,  0.49997455,
        0.49999587,  0.4999641 ,  0.4999488 ,  0.50001366,  0.50000301])
>>> experiment.nbytes
1000000000
>>> experiment.nbytes * 1e-9 # plenty of RAM to spare
1.0
```

On my relatively modest laptop:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("experiment = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100000, 1000, 10), dtype=np.uint8)", "import numpy as np", number=10)
29.73300809401553
>>> _ / 10
2.973300809401553 # seconds per experiment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) to create a matrix of random values 0 <= x < 1 and then use a treshold of <0.5 to alias that to values 0 or 1.

```
numpy.random.rand(10000, 1000, 10)
```